# Opening a file in the user's home directory

Tags: ocaml, filenames, ocaml-core

I've run into a strange problem using `Core.In_channel` library. Here's a piece of code meant to open a file in the user's home directory

```
open Core.Std
In_channel.with_file "~/.todo_list" ~f:(fun in_c ->
  (* Do something here... *)
)
```

However, when running this, here is what I get:

```
Exception: (Sys_error "~/.todo_list: No such file or directory").
```

I am absolutely sure that `~/.todo_list` exists, but I suspect that the filename is misinterpreted by OCaml.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `~` is special for Unix shell, where the shell will automatically expand them.  Check your ocaml module on how to to expand `~` to full user path.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. I'm looking into this right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, the expansion of `~` is done by the shell, not by the underlying system. No shell is involved in your call to `with_file` so the string is interpreted literally as a file name.

If the code is running on behalf of a user who has logged in, the home directory is available as the value of the environment variable `HOME`.

```
# Unix.getenv "HOME";;
- : string = "/Users/username"
```

Otherwise you will need to extract the home directory from the user database.

```
# let open Unix in (getpwnam "username").pw_dir;;
- : string = "/Users/username"
```